# Future[Option[T]]: Keep future if Option is defined otherwise fallback to another future

Tags: scala, future

I have this `val cacheElement:Future[Option[T]]` and the desired result is to keep this future if the `Option` is a `Some` or create another `Future[Option[T]]` based on another service if the future is a `None`. Using pattern matching this would look like that:

```
val cacheElement:Future[Option[T]] = cache.get[T](cacheKey)

for {
    opt <- cacheElement flatMap {
        case Some(cached) => Future { Some(cached) } 
        case None => createFallback(args)
           }
} yield { opt match {
        case Some(_) => //do something
        case None => // Do something else   
    }
}


def createFallback[T](args:T):Future[Option[T]] = ???-
```

How can I do that in a more elegant and sucinct way? This repetition of `Future { Some(cached) }` looks very verbose to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

type T = String

val cacheElement: Future[Option[T]] = Future.successful(Some("asd"))
val failElement: Future[Option[T]] = Future.successful(None)

def createFallback: Future[T] = Future.successful("fallback")

val s = cacheElement.flatMap(_.fold(createFallback)(Future.successful))
val f = failElement.flatMap(_.fold(createFallback)(Future.successful))

Await.result(s, 1.second)
//res0: T = asd
Await.result(f, 1.second)
//res1: T = fallback
```

Answer (score 3):

[`OptionT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) monad transformer from cats provides `orElse` syntax like so

```
OptionT(cacheElement) orElse OptionT(createFallback(args))
```

for example

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object OptionTExample extends App {
  val f: Future[Option[Int]] = Future(None)
  def fallback: Future[Option[Int]] = Future(Some(-1))
  val v = OptionT(f) orElse OptionT(fallback)
  v.value.map(println)
}
```

outputs

```
Some(-1)
```